「先生の専攻は英語ではありませんでした。」or 「先生の専攻は英語ませんでした。」?
I'm trying to find out the correct translation for "Teacher's major was not English." I'm currently learning the Past Tense of Verbs on Genki 1, and for past-negative, it says that "〜ませんでした" is used, but when I went on to Google Translator, it shows "では" after the word "英語." What does "では" do in that sentence? And which sentence is correct: "先生の専攻は英語ではありませんでした" or "先生の専攻は英語ませんでした" ?

ませんでした must always follow the masu-stem (aka pre-masu-form) of a verb, such as 食べ, 歩き, and 言い. However, 英語 is not a verb but a simple noun, and that's why you cannot directly connect 英語 and ません.
To say "is not <noun>", you need to say "<noun>ではありません". You have learned how to say something like これは本ではありません ("This is not a book"), right? You can form its past version simply by adding でした at the end.
Compare the following sentences:

先生の専攻は英語です。
Teacher's major is English. (present)
先生の専攻は英語でした。
Teacher's major was English. (past)
先生の専攻は英語ではありません。
Teacher's major is not English. (negative present)
先生の専攻は英語ではありませんでした。
Teacher's major was not English. (negative past)

(By the way, this あり is actually a kind of verb, but you may forget this fact now.)

Ohh, I see, thank you!
